# What is the "Mint-Effect"?

Tags: kittens-game

The tooltip of the Mint says

> 0,007 mintEffect

But what does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Brilliand's answer in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186670/is-the-mint-building-or-hunting-more-effective), Mints give a certain amount of furs and ivory per tick in exchange for a cost in gold and catpower.

The reason it doesn't just say "x.xx furs per second" or something like that is because the amount of furs and ivory gained is based on your maximum catpower, rather than being a particular amount.  Thus, you get a certain amount of "mintEffect" which then translates through your maximum catpower and becomes ivory and furs.  The linked question includes the exact amounts (and the points that mints become a more effective use of catpower than manual hunting, although you'll likely still be best served doing both).